# How to force set (not subtract) permissions to future files?

Tags: ubuntu, chmod, umask, setfacl

I have a program on Ubuntu Linux that creates a `logs/error.log` file with a permissions `660` (`rw-rw----`) or `640` (`rw-r-----`). But I want the file permissions always to be `666` (`rw-rw-rw-`) (including when the program creates the file).

Restrictions:

1. I can't modify the program. Therefore, I can't change `660` mode using by the program for a new files.
2. The program can recreate the file at any time. Therefore, the solution with a single manual execution of `chmod` is not suitable.
3. I need to add a bits of permissions, but not subtract. Therefore, `umask` and `setfacl` are not suitable.

Comment: Can you explain the situation more thoroughly? Why does a log file need to be executable?

Comment: Exactly why would you want a logfile to be executable? If some fool *does* execute it, it will throw a million syntax errors. And, just possibly, it may contain an actual valid command that may be destructive. You can get `666` by exporting your `umask` as `000`, but that would apply to all files, and anyway many applications over-ride that for their own reasons.

Comment: Additionally, is the program actually setting the log file to 660 or is it just using the default umask? A more thorough explanation of your scenario is necessary. Umask and setfacl can both be used to grant new files more permission. Please explain your 3rd restriction more.

Comment: Natolio, it is my mistake. I mean 666 (rw-rw-rw-), not 777. I need it for docker. Without `rw` mode for `other` I can't edit the mysql log files in mounted as volume folder from host.

Comment: `umask 0` and `setfacl` are not working. I assume mysql does something like `touch error.log; chmod 0660 error.log;`

Comment: I want to find a general way to solve the problem. Not just for mysql. Ideally, I want to find a way to set all future files in the folder to `666` mode without the ability to change them through a `chmod`, etc.

Comment: I want to use it for the development only. Therefore, security is not a problem.

Comment: nah. Making the file world-writable is the wrong solution to this problem. Your actual problem is "how do I give a docker container rights to change a 660 file that belongs to `user:group`"; changing the file to `666` is simply the wrong approach here; instead, you'd change the group membership of the process trying to access it.

Comment: The docker container has rights to change `660` file. The problem is "how do I give rights to host user (different on each developer computer) to change `660` file without making changes outside the docker container".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inotify` to track your file or directory where it is created so you can update its permissions when it is created

Comment: Thanks, it works! I added the final solution in your answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: @MihailH. I would not suggest a solution with world-writable permissions. Please post this solution as your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If all other more sane options are out (like choosing a suitable user/group for the mystery log-creating program that is compatible with whatever you want to do from the docker host, or modifying the configuration of the program so it uses the right permissions), you can use the `LD_PRELOAD` trick:

Hook it whatever syscall your mystery program uses to create the file (probably `creat` or `open`, check with `strace`). Then compare the filename, and modify the `mode` for your logfile only.

This requires you to know how to program in C.

Answer (score 0):

**Final solution** for running inside a docker container:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd logs
umask 0
find . -type f -not -name ".gitignore" -exec chmod 666 \{\} \;
inotifywait -rmq -e attrib -e create -e moved_to --format "%w%f" --exclude "/\.gitignore" . | xargs -n1 -d"\n" chmod 666
```

**Since the solution set world-writable permissions it is not recommended for use as is. Try to find another way that uses a safer permissions.**

Thanks to AlexD for the hint!